# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext: snakeyaml dependency issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, snakeyaml

Due to snakeyaml vulnerability, I am trying to exclude it in spring-boot-starter-web using exclusions

```
dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

I have a testcase which uses @ContextConfiguration tag from springboot

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MongoConfig.class)
public class MongoConfigTest {
MongoConfig classUnderTest = new MongoConfig(); ...
```

This testcase is failing due to below error:

```
<error message="Failed to load ApplicationContext" 
    type="java.lang.IllegalStateException">java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load 
    ApplicationContext
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempted to load Config resource 'class path 
    resource [application.yml]' via location 'optional:classpath:/' but snakeyaml was not 
    found on the classpath
  </error>
```

How to resolve this issue?

```
Spring-Boot version: 2.5.13
java: 11
```

Comment: snakeyml is used to load the application.yml. If you don't want to use snameyml you have to use application.properties instead of application.yml

Answer (score 0):

I removed these three tags which was responsible for loading the application context

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MongoConfig.class)
```

This worked for me. Is there any better way to tackle this issue?

Comment: So you basically disabled the test...

Comment: I did not disable the test, i removed the tags and rerun the test

Comment: Which basically disables the test as now there is nothing spring related being loaded anymore. Those annotations did that and probably you needed that. Hence now while it runs it probably doesn't do anything anymore. However the error you get indicates you are loading a yaml file but removed the library that is capable of loading yaml. So if you remove snakeyaml you loose that ability and you need to move the `application.yml` to `application.properties`. Instead of removing it whatyou should have done is add `<snakeyaml.version>1.31<snakeyaml.version>` to the `<properties>` in maven.

Comment: @M.Deinum I believe lastest version of snakeyaml also have vulnerability if I'm not wrong

Comment: Then don't load yaml, but you cannot have both. Not have a library supporting to load yaml and wanting to load yaml. Latest version shouldn't have the vulnerability that has been fixed.

Comment: See https://security.snyk.io/package/maven/org.yaml:snakeyaml (which has 0 vulnerabilities for Snakeyaml).

Comment: But the lastest version in maven mentions about the vulnerability https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.33

Comment: Which is wrong, as it is fixed in 1.33.